# Print and Export Functionality on web GIS application built with OpenLayers+GeoExt+Extjs+Heron Configuration

Tags: printing, openlayers-2, mapfish, heron-mapping-client

I have used **OpenLayers+Extjs+GeoExt+Heron** configuration to create a thin mapping client. I have added print icon to the client using `heron.options.map.toolbar` (`type: printdialog, options: {printURL etc}`).

I have also the mapfish printing e.g. `config.yaml` in the geoserver data directory and validation of this installation via `xxx/geoserver/pdf/info.json` shows the print options as expected. However back to the app, whenever I click on the print icon, I get an error saying:

```
Error getting print options from server: undefined.
```

Has anyone experienced this and have solved this problem?

Comment: Where have you defined the server? Are you using a proxy to circumvent the same-origin-policy?